# I have a problem with the buttons in java swing

Tags: java, swing

Greeting !
I have a problem, it's java, I made a gui keyboard
(similar to a calculator) and two textfields. and now i don't know how to use the same keys on the keyboard to type in different textfields as needed
(not to type in both textfields at the same time)?
Thanks

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   String s  = jTCena.getText();
            jTCena.setText(s+"1");
}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     String s  = jTCena.getText();
            jTCena.setText(s+"2");
}                                        

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String s  = jTCena.getText();
            jTCena.setText(s+"3");
}                                        

private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   String s  = jTCena.getText();
            jTCena.setText(s+"4");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> i don't know how to use the same keys on the keyboard to type in different textfields as needed

You can define a custom `TextAction` and add it to your buttons.

The `TextAction` allows you to track the last text component that had focus (before you click on the button).

Something like:

```
class KeyboardAction extends TextAction
{
    private String letter;

    public KeyboardAction(String letter)
    {
        super(letter);
        this.letter = letter;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JTextComponent component = getFocusedComponent();
        component.setCaretPosition( component.getDocument().getLength() );
        component.replaceSelection( letter );
    }
}
```

You then use the class like:

```
jButton1 = new JButton( new KeyboardAction("1") );
jButton2 = new JButton( new KeyboardAction("2") );
```

or you add the Action to an existing button by using:

```
button.setAction( new KeyboardAction("1") );
```